# Assign pointers in constructor, what is good practice

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

Say I've created object `A` from a class `A'`. Object `A` takes quite of lot of arguments to it's constructor.

In object `B` from class `B'` I want to store an instance of `A'`. However class `B'` also wants quite a lot of arguments in it's constructor. Instead of passing all the arguments for `A'` to the constructor I'm reasoning that its better to first create an instance of `A'` and then send a reference to it to the constructor of `B'`, instead of creating an even bigger mess of arguments.

In c++ it would look something like this:

```
class A'
{
   A'(arg1, arg2,...argn);


}A(arg1, arg2,...argn);


class B'
{
   public:
   B'(arg1, arg2,...argn, A'* aptr)
   A'* myA; 

}B(arg1, arg2,... argn, &A);
```

Is this good code practice? Also I wonder how the I best assign pointers via the constructor? I've so far done something like this

```
myConstructor( object* __pointerToAnotherObjectStoredInThisObject)
{
      pointerToAnotherObjectStoredInThisObject =     __pointerToAnotherObjectStoredInThisObject;

};
```

It sure works, but is it neat, good practice etc?

Comment: That code hurts my eyes.

Comment: Is the single quote really part of the classes name?

Comment: Are you writing `C++` classes as `C` style structs. And what is up with the long variable names ?

Comment: Drop that single quote, please.

Comment: I'd keep A abstracted away. The called shouldn't need to know B has an A in it. If this is what you're asking.

Comment: Probably single quotes are illegal in c++ class names, but it's the principle I'm after. The long variable name is for making it selfexlplanatory what I try do do. 

If theabove code is bad practice, I would love if you could tell me why and give an example of a better way to do it.

Comment: Just pass all the parameters you need through B. There's nothing wrong with that. More often than not, B can provide some arguments to A that didn't come from the constructor of B.

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, don't really want to store pointers in objects if you can avoid it.  If possible, just store a reference.  It makes the object un-copyable, which stops you from somehow continuing to use the second class after its dependency has been destroyed.

Also, the proper notation for initializing member variables, including pointers, is this...

`myConstructor (object __foo) : foo(__foo) { }`

Here's a really rudimentary example of a class which stores another class as a member, using references.

```
// Let's suppose we're implementing an XML file handling class.
// We decide to put the file handling operations in one class and 
//   let the XML stuff wrap around that file class.

class File {
  // Implement file opening/writing here
};


class XMLFile {
  // Implement XML opening/writing nonsense here.
  File & m_file;

  XMLFile (File & f);
};

XMLFile::XMLFile (File & f) : m_file(f)  {
}
```

Comment: Great, this answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful passing pointers to constructors and then assigning them to a field. Even if you are careful it can be difficult to make sure that the data pointed to be the pointer is not released while it is still in use. Additionally it can be hard to work out when it is safe to release the memory.

Consider having the object keep it's own copy of the data pointed to by the pointer or use a shared_ptr.

Comment: The answer to this is definitely DO NOT use a pointer. There is no need to here, just to avoid a lot of arguments going into B's constructor.

Comment: Only the OP can know whether a reference, pointer, or copy is more appropriate for their real life code.  What if `A'` is huge and `B'` never outlives it?

Comment: That's a totally difference situation. I didn't say never use pointers ever, I said in the example he gave us, he should not use them. Especially not to just avoid a bunch of arguments. Regardless of whether he actually needs a pointer or not has nothing to do with his question.

Comment: The application is in embedded programming, so for performance reasons all objects are created statically at compile time. Object A and B will thus exist forever.

Comment: @user3050215
If there are no lifetime concerns then a C++ reference would be syntactically cleaner than a pointer.